# Snapshot Backups for qemu VMs on Centos

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, centos7, qemu, snapshot

we are running a couple of qemu/kvm based VMs in a pcs cluster which I want to backup via live snapshots.

currently we use qcow2 disk images so there is the possibity to use the qcow external snapshot mechanism but I really dislike that option since it requires to parse and write a lot of xml stuff to keep the vm config in sync witch the diskfiles (every snapshot means that there is a new disk file and the VM always uses the newest one)
Of course this is possible but there are quite some parts that might break and in my experience thats exactly the kind of stuff you discover at 04:00 am when something died and you need to recover it.

Besides that we might move away from qcow2 in the near future and therefore i would like to have a system that works regardless of the backing file.

I run over the kvm incremental backup feature (http://wiki.qemu.org/Features/IncrementalBackup) which looks as it did exactly what I am looking for. Downside: As far as I can tell it needs qemu 2.5+ to be usable and we are using centos7 for our HV which I was not able to find recent qemu packets for.

so my question to the community: Is there any way to archive something similar to whats offered by kvm incremntal backups without compiling a more recent qemu version myself?

BR
Alex

Comment: Usually, when a useful feature hits an upstream package (qemu 2.5 for example), it gets backported into EL, so I think it's just a matter of time. In fact, I think I saw something to that effect on the Centos virt SIG  recently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Centos already has qemu-kvm 2.6 in the repos[1], if it's not official yet, it probably will become official soon:

[1] http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/virt/x86_64/kvm-common/qemu-kvm-ev-2.6.0-27.1.el7.x86_64.rpm

Comment: ohhh great - just updating my testserver